# Having issues filtering regex results using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

**Background**

I have a script that runs an nmap command on every subnet (about 200 subnets, including some /16's, 260k addresses total) in my organization, and dumps a txt log file in a folder, with each folder being one subnet.

I am currently writing a separate script to to read the txt file in each folder, and pull specific info for my digestion.

---

**Current Issue**

See what RegEx I have so far, with my input:

https://regex101.com/r/wUHyZm/1

Currently, I have regex that can successfully match the 'device name (if applicable) +  IP'.

However, this will just grab all devices.

Sample input:

```
Nmap scan report for Device1.domain.com (10.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.027s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
79/tcp open  finger
80/tcp open  http
```

My regex currently will grab:

```
Device1.domain.com (10.0.0.1)
```

And all of the other device(IP) in the files.

I want to be able to only show the device name + IP, for ones that have

```
23/tcp open  telnet
```

Below them

But I'm not sure how to incorporate that with regex.

Once I have this figured out, I'll write my script so that it'll prompt user input for "what port do you want to show", so I can assign '23', '21', etc as a variable. I can handle that part though.

**EDIT**

Would just having two separate regex statements be my solution? I'll give that a shot

Ex (psudo code):

```
If (match $regexA && match $regexB) {
    Code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To offer an alternative to [Ansgar Wiechers' helpful `Select-String` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57677298/45375), based on direct use of the [`[regex]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex) .NET type, which speeds things up:

```
# Sample input.
$txt = @'
Nmap scan report for Device1.domain.com (10.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.027s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
79/tcp open  finger
80/tcp open  http
Nmap scan report for Device2.domain.com (10.0.0.2)
Host is up (0.027s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
79/tcp open  finger
80/tcp open  http
Nmap scan report for Device3.domain.com (10.0.0.3)
Host is up (0.027s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
79/tcp open  finger
80/tcp open  http
'@

[regex]::Matches(
  $txt,
  '(?m)^Nmap scan report for\s+(?<Device>.+)\r?\n(?:.+\r?\n){3}23/tcp open  telnet$'
).ForEach({ $_.Groups['Device'].Value })
```

Note the assumption:

- If the line  `23/tcp open  telnet` is present for a device-related block of lines, it is assumed to always be the *5th* line in that block.
- As per your own comment, it's easy to extend the solution to cover a *range* of subsequent lines, by replacing `{3}` in the regex with `{3,6}` to cover the 5th through the 8th line, for instance.

The above yields the following, showing that only those devices matched that were followed by `23/tcp open telnet` on the 4th subsequent line:

```
Device1.domain.com (10.0.0.1)
Device3.domain.com (10.0.0.3)
```

---

**Explanation:**

- [`[regex]::Matches($txt, '...')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Matches_System_String_System_String_) matches input text `$txt` against regex `...` and returns a collection (of type [`MatchCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection%60)) of *all* matches found.
- `.ForEach({ $_.Groups['Device'].Value })` iterates over all the matches , extracts the text that the named capture group `Device` matched (and implicitly outputs it):

  - Each match is a [`Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) instance whose `.Groups` property contains the collection (of type [`GroupCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection)) of capture-group matches as [`Group`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group) instances, whose `.Value` property contains the matching *text* as a string.
  - Generally, the entry at index `0` of the groups collection is always present and contains what the regex *as a whole* captured; actual capture-group matches are available either by positional *index* (`1` for the 1st capture group in the index, `2` for the 2nd, ...) or, if they are *named* capture groups (`(?<name>...)`), they can be accessed by that name (`$_.Groups['name']`), as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

When using `Select-String` you can specify how much context (lines before and/or after the actual match) should be included with the result. That allows you to filter the match by what's in the context.

```
$input_sample = @'
Nmap scan report for Device1.domain.com (10.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.027s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
23/tcp open  telnet
79/tcp open  finger
80/tcp open  http
'@.Split("`n")

$port = 23

$input_sample |
    Select-String -Pattern 'your pattern' -Context 0,5 |
    Where-Object { $_.Context.PostContext -match "${port}/tcp open" } |
    Select-Object -Expand Line
```

Comment: I see, so "context 0,5" specifies how many lines, but I have variable new lines. If I have a device with the first 23 services open, it'll be 25 or so lines down, but if port 23 is the only service open, it'll be like 3 lines down. The link in my post has a better idea of my sample input

Comment: Actually, I don't think there are ever any ports below 20, so this would work. Thank you sir! This is an acceptable answer.

Comment: Quick question @Ansgar Wiechers, how would I use $input_sample after piping all the arguments in that fashion to it?

Comment: @Ghawblin I don't understand what you mean by that. `$input_sample` contains your `nmap` output, which should be an array of strings. The pipeline I posted does not modify the variable or assign anything to it.

Comment: My input sample is actually a "Get-Content", so I'm just trying to figure things out.

I'm fairly new with Powershell, when you pipe arguments (Select string, where object, etc) like you did above, does that modify anything? I guess I'm not sure what having $input_sample piped to those arguments are supposed to do if it isn't modfying some sort of variable. This is mostly a lack of knowledge in my part though.

Comment: Just pipe the output of `Get-Content` directly into `Select-String`. Or, even simpler, have `Select-String` read the file by itself (parameter `-Path`).